# Compare two dictionaries in vb.net with system.linq

Tags: vb.net, linq, dictionary

Hello I'm trying to compare two vb.net dictionaries to list the difference between the two dictionaries. I have imported the System.Linq and System.Collections.Generic. My dictionaries are being populated correctly but then when i go to compare the two dictionaries I'm getting the following error

> System.Linq.Enumerable+d__99`1[System.String]

Both dictionaries contain the same key's just different order I'm using the following statement to compare (and get the exceptions) not sure what I messed up (if I'm doing this right!) or where I have gone wrong. But if someone could point me into the correct direction that would be greatly appreciated.

```
Dim folder As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
Dim fdatabase As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
Dim different_files 
different_files = folder.Keys.Except(fdatabase.Keys)
```

Comment: Which line throws the exception?  What's the full text of the exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Linq.Enumerable+d__99'1[System.String]` is not an exception. It's the name of a type.

You probably called `.ToString()` on the result of `folder.Keys.Except(fdatabase.Keys)`, maybe implicitly.

---

The code you posted should work fine.

This

```
Dim folder = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer) From {{"Foo", 1}, {"Bar", 2}}
Dim fdatabase = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer) From {{"Foo", 1}, {"Buzz", 4}}

Dim different_files = folder.Keys.Except(fdatabase.Keys)
For Each key In different_files
    Console.WriteLine(key)
Next
```

will print

> Bar

You probably didnt't handle your result correctly. Please enable `OPTION STRICT ON`; it will help you catch errors early on.

Comment: Appreciate that help sloth, i screwed up and was referencing the wrong thing later down in my code but didn't realize at the top i still had a response being written.